# For react-bootstrap-table2, how do you default all the checkbox items to selected?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, bootstrap-table, react-bootstrap-table

If I have a table of data items, and I want to have the ALL the check boxes selected?

so on when page loads and shows table, all table items with checkboxes should be checked.

`<BootstrapTable selectRow={{ mode: 'checkbox', clickToSelect: true}} />`

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I was able to find the answer.

https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/row-select-props.html#selectrowonselectall-function

react-bootstrap-table2 has a function...selectRow.onSelectAll - [Function]

```
const selectRow = {
 mode: 'checkbox',
 onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows, e) => {
   if (isSelect && SOME_CONDITION) {
     return [1, 3, 4];  // finally, key 1, 3, 4 will being selected 
   }
 }
};



onSelectAll = ( isSelected ) => {
    if ( isSelected ) {
        return this.props.myReducer.myDataItems.map( row => row.DATA_TABLE1 );
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

and then selectRow.selected - [Array]
selectRow.selected allow you have default selections on table.
I used this function and passed in 'isSelected: true'

```
 <BootstrapTable
   classes={styles.myDataGrid}
   striped hover
   keyField="DATA_TABLE1"
   data={invalidCrashes}
   selectRow={{ mode: 'checkbox', clickToSelect: true, selected: this.onSelectAll( { 
   isSelected: true } )  }}                                                                         
  />
```

Passing in 'isSelected: true' defaults all the checkboxes to render as 'selected'